# How to display all the mysql tables and their data which is display in same page like in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

How to display all the databse tables in left side and thoer data in right side on the same page as like in phpmyadmin for import-export purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can show table using this query:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$tableList = array();
  $res = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW TABLES");
  while($cRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
    $tableList[] = $cRow[0];
  }

echo '<ul>';
foreach($tableList as $table){
    echo '<li><a href="detail.php?table_name='.$table.'">'.$table.'</a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Make `detail.php`

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_GET['table_name'])){
    $table_name = $_GET['table_name'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i = 0;
echo '<table>';
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
       if($i ==0 ){
           echo '<tr style="background:lightgray">';
           foreach($row as $column => $value) {    
                  echo '<th>' . $column.'</th>';
           }
           echo '</tr>';
           $i=1;
       }

       echo '<tr>';
       foreach($row as $column => $value) {    
              echo '<td>' . $value.'</td>';
       }
       echo '</tr>';
   }
  echo '</table>';

}
```

Comment: but how to perform import-export and browse data options

Comment: style as your wish

Comment: thanks, btw can i add some features like exporting .csv file into database??

Comment: accept answer if i did something for you.